# php taking a large array and sorting its times by there dates into new records of one record with data with all the times associated with it

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a database of punch in times, I need to have them exported to a pdf (which i can do) in a certain format. 
The records have a single date with a punch in and out times (along with other data that needs to be carried over):

```
Date     Punch IN     Punch OUT
```

I need to format the data for export so that any dates that have multiple punch in and outs have all the times on the same line/record. So I can export it like so in the pdf:

```
Date     Punch IN(1)   Punch OUT(1)   Punch IN(2)   Punch OUT(2) (ETC)
```

My issue is I use the below code to go through the initial array containing all the records and the export is almost correct, but for some reason the first record gets overwritten by the last one. So I always lose the first record and I obviously need to fix it, but for the life of me I can't.

The below code is what is creating the new array so that I can export it out on the pdf (I know how to do that).

```
$punchpdfexport = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'Total'=> '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
  $punchpdfexportprev = null;

  $pdfexportpunch = array();

  $previousrow = '';
  $previouscount = 0;
  $count = 0;
  $length = count($punch);
  $check = 0;

  foreach ($punch as $row){
    if ($previousrow != '' && $previousrow->PunchINDate == $row->PunchINDate){
      $count += 1;
      if(($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 1){
        $punchpdfexporttwo = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'Total'=> '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Date = $punchpdfexportprev[0]->Date;
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->IN = $punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN;
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->OUT = $punchpdfexportprev[0]->OUT;
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->IN_2 = $row->PunchInTime;
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->OUT_2 = $row->PunchOutTime;
        $result = $this->functions->secondssum($row->TotalTime,$punchpdfexportprev[0]->Total);
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Total = $result.":00";
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->NotesIN = $punchpdfexportprev[0]->NotesIN . $row->NotesIN;
        $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->NotesOut = $punchpdfexportprev[0]->NotesOut . $row->NotesOut;
        if ($check == $length - 1){
          $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexporttwo;
          break;
        }
      }elseif (($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 2){
        $punchpdfexportthree = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'IN_3' => '', 'OUT_3' => '', 'Total' => '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->Date = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Date;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->IN = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->IN;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->OUT = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->OUT;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->IN_2= $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->IN_2;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->OUT_2 = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->OUT_2;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->IN_3 = $row->PunchInTime;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->OUT_3 = $row->PunchOutTime;
        $result = $this->functions->secondssum($row->TotalTime,$punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Total);
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->Total = $result.":00";
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->NotesIN = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->NotesIN . $row->NotesIN;
        $punchpdfexportthree[0]->NotesOut = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->NotesOut . $row->NotesOut;
        if ($check == $length - 1){
          $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexportthree[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexportthree;
          break;
        }
      }elseif (($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 3){
        $punchpdfexportfour = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'IN_3' => '', 'OUT_3' => '', 'IN_4' => '', 'OUT_4' => '', 'Total'=> '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->Date = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->Date;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->IN;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->OUT;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN_2= $punchpdfexportthree[0]->IN_2;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT_2 = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->OUT_2;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN_3= $punchpdfexportthree[0]->IN_3;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT_3 = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->OUT_3;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN_4 = $row->PunchInTime;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT_4 = $row->PunchOutTime;
        $result = $this->functions->secondssum($row->TotalTime,$punchpdfexportthree[0]->Total);
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->Total = $result.":00";
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->NotesIN = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->NotesIN . $row->NotesIN;
        $punchpdfexportfour[0]->NotesOut = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->NotesOut . $row->NotesOut;
        if ($check == $length - 1){
          $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexportfour[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexportfour;
          break;
        }
      }elseif (($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 4){
        $punchpdfexportfive = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'IN_3' => '', 'OUT_3' => '', 'IN_4' => '', 'OUT_4' => '', 'IN_5' => '', 'OUT_5' => '', 'Total' => '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->Date = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->Date;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->IN = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->OUT = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->IN_2= $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN_2;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->OUT_2 = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT_2;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->IN_3= $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN_3;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->OUT_3 = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT_3;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->IN_4= $punchpdfexportfour[0]->IN_4;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->OUT_4 = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->OUT_4;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->IN_5 = $row->PunchInTime;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->OUT_5 = $row->PunchOutTime;
        $result = $this->functions->secondssum($row->TotalTime,$punchpdfexportfour[0]->Total);
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->Total = $result.":00";
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->NotesIN = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->NotesIN . $row->NotesIN;
        $punchpdfexportfive[0]->NotesOut = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->NotesOut . $row->NotesOut;
        if ($check == $length - 1){
          $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexportfive[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexportfive;
          break;
        }
      }
    }else{
      if ($previouscount < $count){
        $previouscount = $count;
      }else{

      }
      if ($count == 0 && $punchpdfexportprev != null){
        $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexport[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexport;
      }elseif ($count == 1 && $check != $length - 1){
        $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexporttwo;
      }elseif ($count == 2 && $check != $length - 1){
        $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexportthree[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexportthree;
      }elseif ($count == 3 && $check != $length - 1){
        $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexportfour[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexportfour;
      }elseif ($count == 4 && $check != $length - 1){
        $pdfexportpunch[$punchpdfexportfive[0]->Date] = $punchpdfexportfive;
      }
      $count = 0;
    }
    if ($count == 0){
      $punchpdfexport[0]->Date = $row->PunchINDate;
      $punchpdfexport[0]->IN = $row->PunchInTime;
      $punchpdfexport[0]->OUT = $row->PunchOutTime;
      $punchpdfexport[0]->Total = $row->TotalTime;
      $punchpdfexport[0]->NotesIN = $row->NotesIN;
      $punchpdfexport[0]->NotesOut = $row->NotesOut;
    }
    if ($previouscount < $count){
      $previouscount = $count;
    }else{

    }
    $previousrow = $row;
    $punchpdfexportprev = $punchpdfexport;
    $check++;
  }
  var_dump($pdfexportpunch);
```

I use the var_dump at the end to see the result of the foreach loop, which is below:

```
 array (size=4)
  '2018-08-22' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[50]
      public 'Date' => string '2018-08-30' (length=10)
      public 'IN' => string '08:49:52' (length=8)
      public 'OUT' => string '09:29:01' (length=8)
      public 'Total' => string '00:45:00' (length=8)
      public 'NotesIN' => string 'testing 1 2 3' (length=13)
      public 'NotesOut' => string '' (length=0)
  '2018-08-28' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[51]
      public 'Date' => string '2018-08-28' (length=10)
      public 'IN' => string '06:13:07' (length=8)
      public 'OUT' => string '13:15:16' (length=8)
      public 'IN_2' => string '05:05:44' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_2' => string '09:54:03' (length=8)
      public 'Total' => string '11:45:00' (length=8)
      public 'NotesIN' => string 'theuhd gdhsjfsdh dfsdhsdjsdg dsdhsd fdsdjsdhj, dgshsgd djssd djsdbsd djdsfsd dfjsdfn. dudhsdsdjj. ffjjdnds dfjfdfd.' (length=115)
      public 'NotesOut' => string '' (length=0)
  '2018-08-29' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[52]
      public 'Date' => string '2018-08-29' (length=10)
      public 'IN' => string '08:04:26' (length=8)
      public 'OUT' => string '11:07:24' (length=8)
      public 'IN_2' => string '11:10:33' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_2' => string '13:09:16' (length=8)
      public 'Total' => string '05:00:00' (length=8)
      public 'NotesIN' => string 'hfgftesting again' (length=17)
      public 'NotesOut' => string 'testdgtesting later' (length=19)
  '2018-08-30' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[56]
      public 'Date' => string '2018-08-30' (length=10)
      public 'IN' => string '08:49:52' (length=8)
      public 'OUT' => string '09:29:01' (length=8)
      public 'IN_2' => string '09:32:16' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_2' => string '11:21:19' (length=8)
      public 'IN_3' => string '11:21:22' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_3' => string '12:24:36' (length=8)
      public 'IN_4' => string '13:52:47' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_4' => string '15:08:54' (length=8)
      public 'IN_5' => string '12:59:10' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_5' => string '13:52:19' (length=8)
      public 'Total' => string '05:45:00' (length=8)
      public 'NotesIN' => string 'testing 1 2 3hello there' (length=24)
      public 'NotesOut' => string '' (length=0)
```

The first record there should be the same as its key 2018-08-22 but instead it is overwritten by the last one 2018-08-30, and I can't figure out why unless its a built in function issue. Otherwise the other 3 records are perfect and working as intended.

As you can see I tried inserting the new array objects into an array using the date as the key SO that this overwriting issue would not happen.

I hope it is just a simple rewrite somewhere so that this will work, if there is a better way of going about this please let me know I imagine there is but after searching around using methods like array_push, array_merge, array_merge_recursive and the like give the same issue or worse.

Comment: I think the structure of your code lends a lot to confusion, there is a lot of duplication in it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I know, trust me I don't like it either but I was planning to simplify it once I got it working. As it stands I dont want to change anything in case I break it more. And thats why I think there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: Well it's too much code to sort through when it's written like that.  I would suggest changing the `IN` and `Out` to arrays, this `IN_{n}` and `OUT_{n}` business is a recipe for disaster.  You can process the IN and OUT arrays after you build the objects,  In fact I would group the data first then in a separate operation build the objects.

Comment: I think you have little to lose by just diving in with a different approach. The current structure is very rigid on top of all the needless duplication.  You'll be happier for it in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to build in one go, which results in this mess

```
'2018-08-30' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[56]
      public 'Date' => string '2018-08-30' (length=10)
      public 'IN' => string '08:49:52' (length=8)
      public 'OUT' => string '09:29:01' (length=8)
      public 'IN_2' => string '09:32:16' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_2' => string '11:21:19' (length=8)
      public 'IN_3' => string '11:21:22' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_3' => string '12:24:36' (length=8)
      public 'IN_4' => string '13:52:47' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_4' => string '15:08:54' (length=8)
      public 'IN_5' => string '12:59:10' (length=8)
      public 'OUT_5' => string '13:52:19' (length=8)
      public 'Total' => string '05:45:00' (length=8)
      public 'NotesIN' => string 'testing 1 2 3hello there' (length=24)
      public 'NotesOut' => string '' (length=0)
```

Group the data in a structure like this:

```
    [ 
       '2018-08-30' => [
          'Date' => '2018-08-30',
          'Punches' => [ 
            ['IN' => '08:49:52', 'OUT' => '09:29:01'],
            ['IN' => '09:32:16', 'OUT' => '11:21:19'],
            ['IN' => '11:21:22', 'OUT' => '12:24:36']
          ],
          'Total' => '05:45:00'
          'NotesIN' => 'testing 1 2 3hello there'
          'NotesOut' => ''
       ],
     ....
     ]
```

Then reprocess that and build your objects.  It will be much easier to do

```
  foreach($Punches as $key=>$punch){
      $postfix = empty($key) ? "" : "_$key";

       $obj->{"IN{$postfix}"} = $punch["IN"];
       $obj->{"OUT{$postfix}"} = $punch["OUT"]; 
 }
```

To add them to the object, also this should allow you to remove all that duplicated code for example look at this:

```
if(($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 1){
    $punchpdfexporttwo = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'Total'=> '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
    $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Date = $punchpdfexportprev[0]->Date;
    ...
}elseif (($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 2){
    $punchpdfexportthree = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'IN_3' => '', 'OUT_3' => '', 'Total' => '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
    $punchpdfexportthree[0]->Date = $punchpdfexporttwo[0]->Date;   
    ...  
}elseif (($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 3){
    $punchpdfexportfour = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'IN_3' => '', 'OUT_3' => '', 'IN_4' => '', 'OUT_4' => '', 'Total'=> '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
    $punchpdfexportfour[0]->Date = $punchpdfexportthree[0]->Date;
    ...
}elseif (($punchpdfexportprev[0]->IN != '') && $count == 4){
    $punchpdfexportfive = array((object)['Date' => '', 'IN' => '', 'OUT' => '', 'IN_2' => '', 'OUT_2' => '', 'IN_3' => '', 'OUT_3' => '', 'IN_4' => '', 'OUT_4' => '', 'IN_5' => '', 'OUT_5' => '', 'Total' => '', 'NotesIN' => '', 'NotesOut' => '']);
    $punchpdfexportfive[0]->Date = $punchpdfexportfour[0]->Date;
    ....
}else{
```

This is all duplicated except for the name of the variable you are putting it in.  It's too much for me to work out a full solution, without a raw dataset to work with.

But hopefully that helps.

> I know, trust me I don't like it either but I was planning to simplify it once I got it working.

That's fine, but that is what comments are for, just comment the old code out, and start on the new.  The problem is this is fundamentally flawed to begin with because the structure you need is not there.  So to fix that you will be re-writing it any way.

Duplication or WET(Write Everything Twice) is a killer, because it impossible to maintain code that has duplication.  If you want to add a field in you have to go edit and add it to all that duplicate stuff, if you miss one you may not realize something is wrong right way and have to pick through all that looking for the one spot you missed something.

Try to write DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) code.  Whenever I see myself writing the same code over and over, I rethink the structure of it, because that is the foundation of your code.  There is no point "fixing" a house whose basement is falling apart.

**UPDATE**

For the first part you want to do something like this (I have no idea what your data looks like, so I am just winging it)

```
     $data = [];
     foreach ($punch as $row){
        $key = $row['date'];
        if(!isset($data[$key])){
           $data[$key] = [
              'Date' => $row['date'],
              'Punches' => [],
              'Total' => 0
              'NotesIN' => ''
              'NotesOut' => ''
           ];
        }

        $data[$key]['Punches'][] = [
            'IN' => $row['IN']
            'OUT' => $row['OUT']
        ];
        $data[$key]['Total'] += $row['Total'];
        $data[$key]['NotesIN'] .= ' '.$row['NotesIN'];
        $data[$key]['NotesOUT'] .= ' '.$row['NotesOUT'];
     }
```

Then after that loop over `$data` and create your objects from it.  You can probably reduce that code by about 80%.  Less code, less bugs, less things to sort through to fix, etc...

There is nothing wrong with looping over the same data twice, if it makes the code more readable that is fine.  Even without doing that I see ways to combine my examples into one.  But readability is number #1 in my book.  Without it you will never find bugs or be able to fix them, because you can't read the code.

The last thing I will say is ask yourself what happens on the 6th punch in, you code only handles 5.  The examples I have shown handle any number of punch ins. My guess is this would reset `$counter` to 0 and overwrite stuff.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much, I modified the code you posted and it does exactly what I need :) I am self taught and I find myself always defaulting to a brute force approach to coding which I always regret later. But if I get stuck on a problem I usually am hesitant to change anything until I can figure out what went wrong. But thank you again for this, it helped a lot!

Comment: I'm self taught too...  Of course I been doing this sense `2008` ... lol ... Good Luck.  Happy coding with PHP.